# css background image not loading in heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a problem that I'm facing.
I tried many times to solve it following stackoveflow but no succes.
the css image is loading on local machine but not on heroku.

style.css.sccs file:

```
#header-section {
    background-image: asset-data-url("Benz-E-Class.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat
        center top;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;    
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

on production.rb:

```
 config.cache_classes = true
 config.serve_static_assets = true
 config.assets.compile = true
 config.assets.digest = true
```

I executed:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.3" 



# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.1.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console

  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug', '3.4.0'

end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma', '2.11.1'
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use 'image-url' syntax for background image and it should work.

Comment: i used background-image: image-url("Benz-E-Class.jpg"); no succes

Comment: Add  background-image: url(/assets/dep.jpg); or background-image: image-url("dep.jpg");

Comment: are you sure your image is under `assets/images/` and not inside other folder within `/images/some-folder`. cause in that case you probably have to include name of the folder as well.

Comment: Also, just to make sure cache is not playing any role here..after making changes..test app in private or incognito window.

Comment: I know this solution might sound weird but can you just try changing the name of your image file and then call it. I remember this happening to me and renaming the file solved it.

Comment: I refresh with ctrl+shift+r to avoid the cache issue. I renamed the file..but still no success.

Comment: can u tell me the path of your image.??